# Can you Pass Func<T,bool> Through a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Func is a serializable class, but yet when I try to pass it as a parameter through a service. I'm told it "isn't a known type". I've tried the solutions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx) to no avail.

Many thanks out there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's work happening to enable it. Check out the [Expression Tree Serialization](https://expressiontree.codeplex.com/) project on the MSDN Code Gallery.

Comment: That's really scary. Expressions are great for application code, but there are some serious security implications for service code.

Comment: Yeah, but I can imagine a sort of "Linq to the Cloud" project where you pass a "where" clause to a service, and it returns, say, the first 100 rows matching that clause.

Comment: For that scenario, perhaps the type of wrapping that Astoria does is the way to go...

Comment: Sure. I guess it depends on what you're trying to do. As I understand Astoria, it's very "single-table" focused - it'd be hard to pass an expression that looked at Order.Customer.Address.State == "CA", for example.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the "where" scenario that you mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

No, basically. You can't pass an `Expression` either, since it talks to `MemberInfo` nodes. Your best bet is a string representation of the predicate.