# Serializing IQueryable<T> to session state server

Tags: .net, linq, session-state

How can I store a LINQ query (i.e. of type `IQueryable<T>`) in SQL Server session state or any other State Server?

Comment: a linq expression for an in-memory collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize the `IQueryable` but you may be able to serialize the expression tree which generates that `IQueryable`. Check out the following question and associated MSDN link.

[Can you Pass Func<T,bool> Through a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567316/can-you-pass-funct-bool-through-a-wcf-service)

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize/deserialize manually the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx) that is associated to IQueriable using the [visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx)

Or check here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, most implementations of `IQueryable` are not serializable, so you can't do that. But anyway, why do you need to do that? If you want to save the *results* of the query, just call `ToList` on the query and store the result in the session

Comment: I am store linq queries in in-proc session until now. Now we wanted to move to a State server due to frequent session expirations on the web server.

Comment: -1 for this is a comment. There are many reasons you may want to keep the expression tree. I used this in a custom pager control implementation.