# How to Serialize System.Linq.Expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, serialization

I am working on WinRT and entity framework (to SQL), the layer that communicates between them is WCF Service.

In the entity framework I am using the Repository Pattern and I have the method:

```
    public IQueryable<User> GetBySearch(Expression<Func<User, bool>> search)
    {
        return this.Context.Users.Where(search);
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when I add it to WCF

```
    [OperationContract]
    IQueryable<User> GetEventBySearch(Expression<Func<User, bool>> search);
```

and:

```
    public IQueryable<User> GetEventBySearch(Expression<Func<User, bool>> search)
    {
        IUser user = new UserRepository();
        return user.GetBySearch(search);
    }
```

But the problem that `Expression<TDelegate>` is not serializable, therefore, WCF can't serialize it.

So I thought to inherit from it and make it `[Serializable]` but the problem that it is a sealed class.

Comment: ... Are you for real?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to serialize system.linq.expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143181/c-sharp-how-to-serialize-system-linq-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sence at all. In fact you try to execute a func in the code of WinRT client on the WCF service. How shoud that work? I think you have to define your own query language that is translated to a expression on the service.