# How can I filter WCF service results using lambda / linq

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, web-services, lambda

I am planning a WCF service to return lists, data, all the usual things.

Now I saw on here ages ago that as of .NET 4.5 you could pass lambda expressions or filters to WCF (I also saw something in a pluralsight video somewhere) that allowed you to write something along the lines of

```
IQuerable<string> GetInfo();
// or
List<string> GetInfo(Expression predicate);
```

Instead of

```
GetInfo(int page, int resultsPerPage, bool sortAsc, string sortColumn);
```

However, as I'm reading around I see lots of conflicting (and old) information saying that this isnt possible.  Is it then at all possible to filter WCF results **before they are returned** via some linq or lambda expression?

**Update**

I have implemented a Service (WCF not WCF Data Services) like so, and I get the expected result.  Is the client actually passing the query to the web service or is it being rendered client side?

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public IQueryable<string> DoWork()
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        for (char c = 'a'; c < 'z'; c++)
        {
            strings.Add(c.ToString());
        }

        return strings.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
Service1 s = new Service1();
var results = s.DoWork();
var results1 = results.Where(str => str == "a"); // works
```

Comment: I would like to know more about it as well. I assume consumer also should have IQuerable implemented. How a Java based consumer will achieve that?

Comment: Found a similar accepted question here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143181/c-sharp-how-to-serialize-system-linq-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx).

Comment: Please define "normal". :)