# Serialize List<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, serialization, .net-4.0

I have a class which contains a `List<Func<T>>`. The class is serializable and will be transferred over WCF. Now, I have problems with contained `List<Func<T>>`. What can I do that this list will also be serializable?

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the list? Is it important that the functions get carried over, or could the object on the other end have an empty list?

Comment: Func<T> isn't serializable - how can it be?  You'd have to serialize the code, which could have any effect, even an OS call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could we save delegates in a file (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132702/could-we-save-delegates-in-a-file-c), and also [can-you-pass-funct-bool-through-a-wcf-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567316/can-you-pass-funct-bool-through-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How would you expect a `Func<T>` to be serialized? It's a pointer to a function - such a thing cannot be serialized.

Comment: Why not? A function pointer is a piece of data like any other. It would be useful for passing function references between AppDomains for example.

Comment: The question was why would you _expect_ it to be serializable? Sure, it might be possible under _some_ circumstances, but why expect that there would be a general capability to serialize it. For instance, such a thing would not be useful if you passed it to Java. Why would it necessarily make sense to serialize it as XML in a manner that would make sense to most consumers?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Obviously it makes no sense to pass a function pointer through a service endpoint. However, binary serialization of delegates is supported, and one might expect it to be, because a) function pointers are data, and b) it's useful for cross-AppDomain work, serializing classes with events, and perhaps more scenarios.