# How to store a Func<T> variable into a HtmlHelper (Html.HiddenFor()) in order to post it back to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to store a `Func<T>` or `Expression<Func<T>>` variable into a Html.HiddenFor(), inside a Razor view, in order to post it back to the controller, but it does not work as expected, as it's stored as a string, and comes back as null to the controller.

I need it to access particular properties of a model, and set them with other data passed to the controller at the same time.

I cannot find setter properties that I could store and use back in the controller to build the `Func<object>` variable (like I would with any complex object).

For instance, I send to the view, a model, containing a list of these:

```cs
new DataConflict<AppointmentEditModel, dynamic, dynamic>(x => x.StartDate, null, Start, appointment.StartDate)
```

then I store the lambda expression `x => x.StartDate`, which is a `Expression<Func<T>>`, like this (it seems to store it as a string):

```cs
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Appointment.ConflictList[i].DataProperty)
```

And when it comes back to the controller after submission, all the lambda containing properties are null.

I expect the controller to receive back the lambda expression containing object, it sent to the view.

Thank you.

Comment: All server values needs to be serializable so that it can be transmitted between client and server. A Func<> nor Expression is serializable. Not sure what the use case is here. But if you must do this you can store a string representing the desired logic and dynamically construct a Func<> based on your string. You will have to write your own code for this as Func<> are not serializable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960793/serialize-listfunct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Van has suggested, I've looked for a way to serialize the data, and I learned that this is not a good thing to do at all, to serialize lambda expressions.

I then have looked for another solution, and decided to use reflection, sending the member name to the client, and then back to the server.

Hope this help.