# WCF service (entity) ¨linq quert select db table through parameter webget possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, wcfserviceclient, webget

i wanted to ask if it possible to select an entity database table through a webget parameter ? here is what it might look like :

```
[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<TestTable> GetAllCallers(string select, string **table**)
    {

        //testCDREntities context = this.CurrentDataSource;

            var Callers = from d in this.CurrentDataSource.**table**
                          select d ;

        return Callers;



    }
```

ofcourse this doesn't work but is there a way to let this work ? 
I hope somebody can help me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>This is impossible. You can't serialize `IQueryable<T>`, therefore you can't send it trough WCF.</s>

The usual way is to pack the properties you need into a serializable Data Transfer Object. We are using [Automapper](http://automapper.org) to map our domain entities to DTOs.

If you are hardcore, take a look at this discussion about [serializing func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567316/can-you-pass-funct-bool-through-a-wcf-service).

It could however be possible to serialize `TestTable[]`. TestTable must be a known class that can be instantiated (i.e. not abstract, not an interface). Also all properties used in the [datacontract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) must be serializable.

```
return Callers.ToArray();
```

`.ToArray()` executes your query, so now you are sending the actual data, not an abstract syntax tree.

--Edit--

Sorry, I was totaly wrong about the impossibility of sending IQueryable over the wire. I totally missed that we are talking about an OData service here. I was thinking about SOAP services all the time. Thanks Rytmis for clearing that up. Googling with the *correct* search terms also turned up this discussion: [Expose IQueryable Over WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291370/expose-iqueryable-over-wcf-service)

Comment: Sorry i typed it wrong but can you select a table from a db through parameters ?

Comment: You could use reflection to get the table type from its name, and then use this type in  `dbContext.Set<TableType>()`. However, it is not possible to return a generic type through WCF. You could however introduce some base type for your tables that contains the common data and return this base type.

Comment: No, it's not impossible. WCF Data Services maps IQueryables to OData queries. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744841(v=vs.110).aspx.