# How can I send a lambda expression to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

`[OperationContract]
 User UserGetFirst(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate);`

it give me boolean serilization error how can I fix this problem?

[This error detail. it is turkish sorry about that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mv7k.png)

Comment: it would be nice to add what kind of error is displayed etc.. is this the complete code of the lambda(no exp with C#)?

Comment: I am add error screen it is turkish sorry about that I hope you understand

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18143181/5311735 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/567316/5311735