# How to work with Expression Trees not working using WCF since they are not serializable?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, expression, func

I have a 4 layered architecture project, i.e. UserInterface, BusinessLogic, Service (WCF) and DataAccess (EF6) layers. I have exposed methods on my service that accept an expression which I can pass to my data access layer to be evaluated using EF. However, this does not work because the `Expression<Func>` is not serializable.

On my client end I want to be able to build queryable expressions to send to the server side and return the correct projection.

Server Side:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Get(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expression)
{
            using (var ctx = MyContext())
            {
                IQueryable<PersonDto> col = ctx.DbContext.People.Where(expression);
                //
                return col.ToList();
            }
}
```

Client side:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonDto> GetFromService(Expression<Func<PersonDto, bool>> expression)
{
    using (MyService client = new MyService())
    {
        return client.Get(expression);
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative to the way I'm doing this? And is there a reason why expressions and funcs are not serializable?

Comment: You can try to use this library: https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq

Comment: Alreay answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567316/can-you-pass-funct-bool-through-a-wcf-service

Comment: Is there a reason to serialize an expression tree vs the string criteria? i.e. pass the string criteria to the server which then builds the expression tree. Serializing expression trees is adding complexity/overhead that makes it difficult to debug/trouble shoot.

Comment: Am I only only person that is not happy with a client passing code to a server, given that this code may do ANYTHING on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Remote.Linq](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq) for this. The Project is currently hosted on GitHub, but it seems that there is no documentation. But you can use the [old one](https://remotelinq.codeplex.com/documentation) from CodePlex.

The easiest way to achieve this (Code copied from the old documentation)

```
// create linq expression
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Order, bool>> linqExpression =
    order => order.Items.Where(i => i.ProductId == prodId).Sum(i => i.Quantity) > 1;

// transform linq expression into serializable expression tree
Remote.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression serializableExpression =
    linqExpression.ToRemoteLinqExpression();

// transform serializable expression tree back into linq expression
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Order, bool>> recreatedLinqExpression =
    serializableExpression.ToLinqExpression<Order, bool>();
```

Answer (score 3):

For your particular scenario, it would be simpler (and probably more secure) to just pass the WHERE condition as a string and use dynamic linq on the server.

```
 using System.Linq.Dynamic;

 public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Get(string condition)
    {
        using (var ctx = MyContext())
        {
            return = ctx.DbContext.People.Where(condition).ToList();
        }
    }
```

More info here: [Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)